# How do I use the awesome window manager?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, documentation, awesome-wm

I've installed awesome on my Ubuntu laptop, and I like it.  But I feel kind of lost.  I don't know any keyboard shortcuts and the man pages aren't really any help (for instance, what does Mod4 mean?).

Is there any kind of brief introduction to awesome I can read?

Comment: Mod4 is the "Wind*ws" Key.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is [one person's introduction](http://urukrama.wordpress.com/2008/07/10/first-steps-with-awesome-window-manager/)

Here is a guide [to installing it with Ubuntu](http://www.actionshrimp.com/2009/02/installing-awesome-window-manager-on-ubuntu-intrepid/)

And here is a [history and additional links via Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awesome_(window_manager))

Hope that helps!

Comment: typo on the Wiki link, the ending curly brace is not linked

Comment: Funny that leaving out the ) will take you to a different page

Comment: Note to people reading this in 2014: the first link refers to an old version of Awesome. Awesome has replaced ini files with the Lua language for ita configuration.

Answer (score 5):

I assume Mod4 is the same as meta which is the Windows key on most modern keyboards.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my bare bones intro to awesome window manager: http://isomorphismes.tumblr.com/post/33846445632/awesome-window-manager. First few lines:

> The main keys you need to know are:
>
> - ⌘+space = change screen layout type
> - ⌘+shift + space = change screen layout type, cycling backwards
> - ⌘+j = go to the next window on this desktop (focus on, as if you had hovered your mouse over it … but without needing to reach over to
>     the mouse)
> - ⌘+k = go to the previous window on this desktop
> - ⌘+J = swap this window and the next one
> - ⌘+K = swap this window and the previous one
> - ⌘+h = → the center partition   squashing the right pane(s)
> - ⌘+l = ← the center partition   expanding the right pane(s)
> - ⌘+← = desktop to the left
> - ⌘+→ = desktop to the right
> - ⌘+9 = desktop number nine
>
> Notice that h,j,k,l are the right-handed home row keys on a
>   QWERTY|AZERTY.

Answer (score 2):

Press `Mod4`+`Enter` (typically this would be the Wind*ws key and Enter) to open a terminal and then enter `man awesome`. A list of default key-bindings is shown.

Answer (score 1):

I recently started out with Awesome too. The links diablomarcus posted are great. You should also check out http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Main_Page
If there exists an answer to any question you can't find on the wiki, which is sometimes a little out of date, you're gonna find it at #awesome on OFTC. They're really helpful, even to the novice. Try to do as much research as possible on the wiki.

Oh, and almost right away you're going to want to change at least one settings, so check out the Configuration page on the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

I just started using Awesome WM myself.

Regarding the sub-question: "What is <kbd>Mod4</kbd>"?

- <kbd>Mod4</kbd> is one of the modifier keys set for the `xserver` currently running
- it can be any physical key you like
- check setting with `$xmodmap -pm`

Yuo can read more from the man pages (`$man xmodmap`) or via Google: [xmodmap keyboard layout](http://www.google.com/search?q=xmodmap%20keyboard%20layout)

You can do some great things with it! Took me a bit to understand it, though.

Answer (score 1):

I put [this](https://gist.github.com/deanrather/dfd70ccb3ade33668aef) together before finding this page.

---

## Using Awesome

- Windows are "Tiled" by default, and you organise the tiles instead of click-dragging windows around.
- `Virtual Desktops` are called `Tags`, there's 9 of them, and they're per-Screen.

### Moving Between Windows

```
Win+J/K         | Prev / Next Window (like Alt+tab)
Win+Ctrl+J/K    | Prev / Next Screen
Win+1-9         | Change to Desktop
```

### Rearranging Windows

```
Win+Space       | Change Screen Layout Type
Win+O           | Move window to Other Screen
Win+Ctrl+Space  | Toggle window Floating/Tiled
Win+Shift+J/K   | Move window to next position
Win+H/L         | Resize window
```

### Other

```
Win+Enter       | New Terminal
Win+Shift+C     | Close Window
```

### Mousey Things

```
Win+Left-Click  | Move
Win+Right-Click | Resize
```